# Why my fixed menu is under my hamburger icon?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

Is it possible to locate the hamburger icon in the fixed menu bar?

I tried to put the  element inside the class="sidenav" in the body tag but the I couldn't find the icon.

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Style the navigation bar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* Navbar links */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <span onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Search</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Expectation**

[image: Expectation]

**Reality**

[image: Reality]

Comment: You are telling the navbar to have a `margin-left: 0`, you're also setting the first `span`with `position: absolute`, this takes it out of the document flow and as such, the remaining items don't treat it like its there. Try setting the navbar to `margin-left: auto`

Comment: @IvanS95 I tried. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I noticed a few things that can be improved on you code, for one, you can use Flexbox to align all items on a single row quite easily; removing the absolute position from the nav icon so everything behaves normally, this also lets you remove the `float` property. Then the you can wrap your links in another div (or a `ul` tag) and push them to right with `margin-left: auto`

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style the navigation bar */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Navbar links */

.navlinks{
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="navbar">
    <span onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
      <div class="navlinks">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Search</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @IvanS95 . The icon is in the menu but the menu size is smaller. Nevermind, I think I know how to fix it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your issue with 2 lines on `CSS`:

```
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/r24uyeq5/

Answer (score 0):

You can set 'margin-left' a value equal to the width of the icon to navBar

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px;//Icon width
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}
```